# Add items to recycler view from another activity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'd like to click a button that adds a bunch of new objects to a recycler view in another activity.

I have Activity A (a Recipe Page) and activity B (Shopping list). I have a menu button in activity A to add all items of a an array (ingredients) to activity B's Recycler View ArrayList.

I have a loop in activity A to go through each ingredient of the array:

```
for (int x = 0; x < recipeIngredients.length; x++) {
     ShoppingList.insertItem(recipeIngredients[x]);
```

}

And a method in Activity B that I use in activity B to add individual items to the recycler view. But when called in activity A (as above), I get null object reference.

Shopping list activity:

```
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
public RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
public static ArrayList<ShoppingItem> mShoppingList;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shopping_list);

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.shopping_listView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mAdapter = new ShoppingListAdapter(mShoppingList);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

}

```
public void insertItem(String ingredient) {
    mShoppingList.add(new ShoppingItem(ingredient));
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: can u call `insertItem` function in `onCreate` ?

Comment: When start another activity, you can use bundle to pass llist of object to another activity for displaying on RecyclerView

Comment: In the same activity, yes and I do add items in oncreate. But i need to add them from another activity also

Comment: I think you can explain it better. Explain the flow of your app by using ActivityA starts ActivityB, List is in ActivityA,..... and so on

Comment: @sontruongit I am not starting an activity after pressing it though, I just want to click the button and stay on the same page, while adding the items. Does bundle work for that?

Comment: Please include the code snippet of your classes in your question to help us to understand in better way @w1lrs7

Comment: There guys, hope that is much more clear and I really appreciate any help

Comment: wait i'll paste my answer with explanation @w1lrs7

Answer (score 1):

I declared an arraylist in Activity B:

```
static ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Added the String 'ingredient' that creates the item in activity A to the arraylist:

```
ShoppingList.listItems.add(ingredient);
```

and then in the oncreate of Activity B, add any items from the arraylist to the shopping list and notify adapter:

```
for(String s : listItems) {
        mShoppingList.add(new ShoppingItem(s));
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```